# Register namespaced class in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5, autoload

I'm trying to implement a library which was written for PSR-0 compliant autoloading in my joomla project. However joomla 2.5 does not support PSR-0 autoloading so I figured that I would have to write my own implementation.

Since I want to use my classes across my entire joomla installation I decided to write a plugin which registers the classes `onAfterInitialise()` but this is where it goes wrong: it overrides joomla's autoloading methods.

The library i'm trying to implement is located at `libraries/Zoho/CRM/ZohoClient.php` with several subfolders. Everything is namespaced with accordance to PSR-0 so starting with: `\Zoho\CRM`.

How do I register the classes in such a way that I can use them globally across joomla? This is my implementation:

```
public function onAfterInitialise()
{

    spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
        $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
        $fileName = '';
        $namespace = '';
        if ($lastNsPos = strripos($className, '\\')) {
            $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
            $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
            $fileName = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        }
        $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

        require $fileName;
    });
}
```

This obviously wont work because it overrides the joomla autoloading function. I'm running php5.3 (5.4 in 3 months)